# XML Serialization to many nodes

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm looking for the following structure

```
<EmailAddresses>
    <Email>email@email.com</Email>
    <Email>email@email.com</Email>
</EmailAddresses>
```

Here is what I have tried

```
[XmlRoot("EmailAddresses")]
public class EmailAddress
{
    [XmlElement("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Writing

```
XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<EmailAddress>), new XmlRootAttribute("EmailAddresses"));
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filename))
{
    writer.Serialize(fs, emailAddresses);
}
```

My current output

```
<EmailAddresses xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <EmailAddress>
        <Email>something here</Email>
    </EmailAddress>
    <EmailAddress>
        <Email>something here</Email>
    </EmailAddress>
</EmailAddresses>
```

one to many nodes

Answer (score -2):

Figured it out

```
[XmlRoot("EmailAddresses")]
public class EmailAddress
{
    [XmlElement("Email")]
    public List<string> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You changed your question after my answer, which is completely different (serializing a single object vs. a list). I deleted mine. -1 for taking my time.

Comment: My original question was about XML serialization and you first posted Linq2XML. I didn't see your next answer until after I posted this. Don't see why that deserves a down vote. More of an ass thing to do.